# How can I identify the bandwidth and flop rate of my CUDA code using visual profiler?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I have attached a screenshot of visual profiler after executing one of my cuda implementation. **I just want to find out bandwidth and the flop rate of my implementation using visual profiler**. Hope the fields that I mentioned in the figure shows the maximum possible bandwidth and flop rate for my GPU. 

Thanks in advance.

[image: Visual Profiler Screenshot]

Comment: Those are hardware peak numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. You need to follow below steps to find the flop rates.

1. Open up the Metrics and Events window (shift + ctrl + E) and mark the instructions in the attached figure.
   [image: step1]
2. Then apply and run.
3. After the execution is finished, you can see the count of flops in the bottom of the step2 figure. 
   [image: step2]
4. Now you have count of different flops. You have to calculate the flop rate by finding out respected execution time however.

Comment: Another method would be profiling the code using nvprof alone with following flags. "/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvprof --print-gpu-trace --metrics flop_count_dp,flop_count_sp,flop_dp_efficiency,flop_sp_efficiency your_program args_if_any".

Comment: if you have set the nvprof path to environment variable, you can use only "nvprof" instead "/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvprof ". To find out more metrics go to the following link. [CUDA Metrics Ref](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference)